# Will I have down time or slowness upgrading my storage to General-purpose v2 storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have some storage accounts that are under load right now. I saw the option to upgrade and I am very eager to do so as it is a little cheaper and has additional features. But I fear having down time or my users becoming slow.

I've found [this article on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-upgrade), but it does not mention down time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no performance impact in the while Upgrading to a
>   general-purpose v2 storage account.

[image]

You can find the details at the bottom of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-upgrade). The feedback part.